# Below code gives strange output

Tags: c, struct

Below code works (no errors) but I get strange output such as this from the code below:

OUTPUT:

Name is         8îk and quantity is       0

Name is        ░îk  and quantity is 2130567168

Where is my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void display(struct item *);

struct item{

char name[50];
int quantity;

};

int main(void){

struct item *first = (struct item *)malloc(sizeof(struct item));
strcpy(first->name, "Banana");
first->quantity = 32;

struct item *second = (struct item *)malloc(sizeof(struct item));
strcpy(second->name, "Apple");
second->quantity = 432;

display(&first);
display(&second);

getch();

}

 void display(struct item *i){

printf("Name is %10s and quantity is %7d\n", i->name, i->quantity);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `first` and `seconds` are already pointers, so you don't need to pass their address, but their value (address of the struct they're pointing at):

```
display(first);
display(second);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
display(first);
display(second);
```

`first` and `second` are already pointers, as required by `display` structure.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the obvious errors when calling `display()`, you are also missing `#include <string.h>`. If you had [compiled with warnings enabled](http://codepad.org/qYEJ076L) you would have been alerted to this, and to the problem with the calls to `display()`, and several other problems too:

```
Line 4: warning: 'struct item' declared inside parameter list
Line 4: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
In function 'main':
Line 16: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcpy'
Line 23: warning: passing argument 1 of 'display' from incompatible pointer type
Line 24: warning: passing argument 1 of 'display' from incompatible pointer type
t.c: At top level:
Line 30: error: conflicting types for 'display'
Line 4: error: previous declaration of 'display' was here
```

The moral of the story: **always compile with warnings enabled, and take heed of any warnings!**

One further point to note: you should [never cast the result of malloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), e.g.

```
struct item *first = malloc(sizeof(struct item)); // do not apply redundant and
                                                  // potentially dangerous cast!
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the address of the pointer to a struct to the function "display" rather than passing the address of the struct itself. (you're passing "struct item **").

display(first);
display(second); will solve the problem.